# Add "onClick" event to a dynamic div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic created div:

```
<div id="submit"></div>
```

and I only want to add a sessionStorage with "onclick", like this:

```
<div id="submit" onClick="sessionStorage.setItem('status', '2')></div>
```

I try something like:

```
<script>
$("#submit").click(function(){ sessionStorage.setItem('status', '2'); });
</script>
```

... but it doesnt work. Maybe I dont add the sessionStorage correctly inside the function? Can anybody help me?

Thats my test-fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net//dwcujtvk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As elements are dynamically created, use [`Event delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

> *Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.*

**Note:** Use `.on` instead of `click` for *dynamically added elements*

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit', function(){ sessionStorage.setItem('status', '2'); });
```

Comment: One moment, I will try it ...

Comment: Not working for me ;(

Comment: Ok, i will create on ...

Comment: I have added a fiddle (on the top)

Comment: Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/dwcujtvk/1/

Comment: Aaah, ok, now it works - big thx for support!!

Comment: I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_